# Верстка приложения с использованием Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

Есть приложение в котором используется карта Google Maps в качестве фрагмента, в приложении так же располагается пользовательский интерфейс, кнопки и текстовые метки,а так же рекламный баннер снизу. Со стороны гугло карт в свою очередь присутствует интерфейс в виде кнопок масштабирования компаса, кнопки возврата к местоположению и сама надпись Google. Интерфейс моего приложения распологается в верхних углах и снизу, соответственно что бы не перекрывать интерфейс гугло карт и их надпись я использую:

```html
mMap.setPadding(0, 100, 0, 300); // start, top, end, bottom
```

Для создания отступа для интерфейса гугл, что бы кнопки и надпись google не перекрывались моими.
Но проблема в том что на разных разрешениях экрана этот отступ фиксируется в пикселях. В моем случае отступ снизу в 300 пикселей на разрешении 1080*1920 располагается как надо, а вот на устройстве с маленьким разрешением, этот отступ становится большим и надпись google поднимается аж на середину, а при повороте экрана кнопки масштабирования и возврата к местоположению начинают наезжать друг на друга. Помогите решить этупроблему.

Comment: Просто задавайте размеры в DP - так они на всех экранах будут одинаковы пропорционально после автоматического перевода в пиксели

Comment: Я бы рад да не получается, не вписывается туда dp ни как, подсвечивается красным.

Comment: Надо получить пиксели из DP. Например  DP хранить в dimens.xml, а программно получать как-то так уже в пикселях: `context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.some_value);`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, будет ли считаться такое решение деликатным, но сделал так:
сначала определяем высоту в пикселях

```html
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

Дальше зная наиболее распространенные разрешения экранов делаем такую конструкцию

```html
if(screenHeight==1920) {
            mMap.setPadding(0, 100, 0, 150);                                                            
        } else if(screenHeight==1280) {
            mMap.setPadding(0, 80, 0, 100);
        } else if //.....и так далее
```

По крайней мере все работает)))